# How to determine the specific H264 encoder in use from FFmpeg library?

Tags: ffmpeg

Looking at h264 encoders supported by FFmpeg library, I see quite a few encoders:

```
libx264
nvenc_h264
h264_nvenc
h264_vaapi
h264_cuvid
h264_vdpau
```

To obtain an H264 encoder, we make a generic call:

```
encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
```

How do we know which encoder was actually picked up? Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the signature of `avcodec_find_encoder()` [here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__encoding.html#ga9f820c481615c3a02d0407bac0bdbf25):

```
AVCodec* avcodec_find_encoder(enum AVCodecID id)
```

It returns an `AVCodec` struct pointer. Then let's see what `AVCodec` struct can tell us [here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodec.html):

```
const char * name
const char * long_name

// Log or print either of them will show you the encoder name.
printf("%s\n", encoder->name);
printf("%s\n", encoder->long_name);
```

And by default, `AV_CODEC_ID_H264` will choose `libx264`.

Another approach is to check ffmpeg source, try to search the encoder ID in `libavcodec/` dir. Usually an encoder `AVCodec` struct will be at the end of a c source file, including the name, long name and ID. For example, the following struct is in `libavcodec/libx264.c`:

```
 AVCodec ff_libx264_encoder = {
    .name             = "libx264",
    .long_name        = NULL_IF_CONFIG_SMALL("libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10"),
    .type             = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,
    .id               = AV_CODEC_ID_H264,
    .priv_data_size   = sizeof(X264Context),
    .init             = X264_init,
    .encode2          = X264_frame,
    .close            = X264_close,
    .capabilities     = AV_CODEC_CAP_DELAY | AV_CODEC_CAP_AUTO_THREADS,
    .priv_class       = &x264_class,
    .defaults         = x264_defaults,
    .init_static_data = X264_init_static,
    .caps_internal    = FF_CODEC_CAP_INIT_THREADSAFE |
                        FF_CODEC_CAP_INIT_CLEANUP,
};
```

About the other codecs, `h264_nvenc` and `nvenc_h264` is the same for NVIDIA GPU encoders; `vaapi` and `vdpau` is supported by various hardwares; and `h264_cuvid` is cuda decoding support, also provided by NVIDIA GPU. If you need any of these codecs, get it by `avcodec_find_encoder_by_name()`.